# Unity3D - Shooting a Ray between Camera and Player - Transparent Walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I"m trying to shoot a ray between camera and player, and when it shoots my wall changes shader to transparent, but for some reason only when I'm in the corner of the wall it disappears. The idea is every time a wall is in between my player and the camera it would disappear.

This script is attached to an empty gameObject.

```
public class WallManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string transparentTag = "Transparent";
    [SerializeField] private Material transparentMaterial;
    [SerializeField] private Material defaultMaterial;

    public LayerMask transparencyMask;


    private Transform _selection;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 transparentTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform.position;

        if (_selection != null)
        {
            var selectionRenderer = _selection.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            selectionRenderer.material = defaultMaterial;
            _selection = null;
        }

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(transparentTarget);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, transparencyMask))
        {
            var selection = hit.transform;
            if (selection.CompareTag(transparentTag))
            {
                var selectionRenderer = selection.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                if (selectionRenderer != null)
                {
                    selectionRenderer.material = transparentMaterial;
                }

                _selection = selection;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to turn around the ray? It might be a problem with the normal of the plane. Because the normal faces the same direction as the ray it will be ignored.

Comment: To make your material Transparent you shouldn't be switching materials but rather changing the Alpha or Shader properties.  This post has examples of both methods.  https://answers.unity.com/questions/1575599/turning-standard-materials-from-opaque-to-transpar.html

Comment: I disagree with @jiveturkey. Changing the material properties can be problematic because often a single material is shared between multiple objects. So if you try to change the material properties of just one object, you may end up changing a bunch of others. Switching materials is fine.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that you aren't using  the `ScreenPointToRay` function properly. Its supposed to take a point on the screen (even though it takes a Vector3; it ignores the z coordinate), but you are passing a point in world space.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(transparentTarget);
```

This function is supposed to take a point on the screen, but you are giving it a point in world space. Try replacing it with this:

```
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(
     new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth/2, Camera.main.pixelHeight/2, 0));
```

This should give you a ray from the center of the camera view to the player (if the camera is pointing directly at the player, that is), which I think is what you were going for. You could also try:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, 
    transparentTarget - Camera.main.transform.position);
```

This will give you a ray pointing from the camera to the player. This code will still work even if the player is not centered in the view of the camera.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked like a charm! I might just disable the walls instead of turning transparent so I don't run the risk of clicking in the wall while it's transparent. But that's a new problem to figure it out hahaha. Thank you again!